# Insert fe_user uid in selectwhere statement

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I'm trying to insert the currently logged in fe_user's UID into a typoscript select statement. I need the total record count based on a few conditions, and get only the number of records that belong to the current user (by recipientuseruid).

There's what I have been trying so far:

```
lib.newMessagesCountLabel = CONTENT
  lib.newMessagesCountLabel {
  table = tx_mygigs_domain_model_message
  select {
    selectFields = count(*) AS count
    pidInList = 20
    where = ( isread='0' AND hidden='0' AND deleted='0' )
    andWhere = recipientuseruid={TSFE:fe_user|user|id}
  }

  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      wrap = |
      data = field:count
    }
  }
}
```

But as you can guess without any luck so far. I'm using TYPO3 6.1.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work either btw:

select {
  selectFields = count(*) AS count
  pidInList = 20
  where = isread=0
  andWhere.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|id
  andWhere.wrap = recipientuseruid=|
}

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
andWhere.dataWrap = recipientuseruid={TSFE:fe_user|user|uid}
```

Btw: Since TYPO3 4.6: "where" is stdWrap also so you can simply write

```
where.dataWrap = isread=0 AND hidden=0 AND deleted=0 AND recipientuseruid={TSFE:fe_user|user|uid}
```

Comment: Hi Krystian, it doesn't work, I tried both solutions. For example:

`where.dataWrap = isread=0 AND hidden=0 AND deleted=0 AND recipientuseruid={TSFE:fe_user|user|id}`

Comment: `where.dataWrap = isread=0 AND hidden=0 AND deleted=0 AND recipientuseruid=1` on the other hand does work (1 is the UID of the fe_user)

Comment: I see now the reason. In TYPo3 there is uid not id. I corrected the answer.